# kotlin multiplatform testing does not work in new project template

Tags: android-studio, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to follow the steps on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kmm-create-first-app.html#run-tests-on-android to get started with multiplatform development. Except no tests are run when I click the icon in the gutter or when I use gradle test
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, Kyle! Is this problem still relevant to you? It looks like this is the same problem that was described at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-8859, maybe some advice from there would help. If not, please extend the question with information about Kotlin and IDE versions used.